# What would happen if deploy PostgreSQL with HDFS as filesystem in high-load scenario?

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, hdfs, high-load

It's a deliberately stupid question. But I'm just curious - what would happen if I mount HDFS using FUSE binding as a volume and launch PostgreSQL with a cluster stored on this HDFS volume and start writing massive amounts of data and/or do high-intensity reading?

Answer (score 6):

First I don't think it's a stupid question, with that said, let's use some definitions and we can continue from that point:

**Fuse:**

> FUSE is a userspace filesystem framework. It consists of a kernel module, a userspace library, and a mount utility (fusermount).

**HDFS (Hadoop Distributed File System):**

> A file system that is distributed amongst many networked computers or nodes. HDFS is fault-tolerant because it stores multiple replicas of files on the file system, the default replication level is 3.

So I think that a short version of your question @Gill Bates is: Does HDFS affect the performance of a Postgres DB (Of course assuming that the Postgres cluster is stored in `HDFS`)?

The short answer is, depends on your configuration but likely yes, as mentioned above you can think of `HDFS` as a file-system, and of course, Postgres stores the data in the file system, so it will be affected by the file system you are using, and let's say you perform multiple operations `read/write`, one of the great advantages of having a distributed file system as `HDFS` is that support multiple replicas of files which
considerably reduces the common bottleneck of many clients accessing a single file so that may help to scale better.

So answering your question directly: what happens if I start writing massive amounts of data and/or do high-intensity reading?

Regardless of your file system is `HDFS` (which may help you to scale better and at the same time add fault tolerance to your file system) or not, the parameters that could determine/affect directly how good your DB responds under stress tests are:

- Indexing
- Partitioning
- Checkpoints
- VACUUM, ANALYZE (with FILLFACTOR)
- Queries definition

And of course, depends on your stack too (how good is your server provided/host), based on my experience these are the facts that may affect more your Postgres DB (attached below some links that may help to clarify more ).

- [DB performance and file system](https://www.quora.com/How-database-performance-is-effected-by-the-file-system)
- [Tunning a Postgres DB](https://severalnines.com/blog/tuning-io-operations-postgresql)

Hope the above helps to clarify!

Comment: thx for the edition @a_horse_with_no_name is more readable now 